# Length of String is longer than Characters of String

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

Why does this happen?

I am getting a string from another class to compare it to a current string, but the if statement didn't work because there is something wrong with the string.  When I tried to check the length, they differ.  How is this possible?

receivedCom = "go";

```
  public string checkaction(string receivedCom)
        {

            print ("-------" + receivedCom + "-------" + receivedCom.Length); //Just to show there isnt any white spaces behind or infront --> OUTPUT IS "-------go-------3"
            print (receivedCom + receivedCom.Replace(" ", "").Length); //Tried removing white spaces if there were any --> OUTPUT "go3"
            string x = receivedCom.Remove(receivedCom.Length-1); 
            print (x + " " +x.Length); --> OUTPUT IS "go 2" (Correct lenght, but if still doesnt want to work with it)

            if("go".Equals(x)){
            return "yes";
            }
            else{return "";}
        }
```

Either something strange is going on, or I'm losing it.

This has been done in a CS script. (Used by Unity.)

UPDATE:

Running the code provided by Jon Skeet, this is my Results

```
Lenght: 3
receivedCom[0] = 103
receivedCom[1] = 111
receivedCom[2] = 13
```

UPDATE : How i Came to get a "carriage return"

```
void Start () {

        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        script = (PlayerScript) player.GetComponent(typeof(PlayerScript));

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"F:\ReceiveRandomInput.exe"; //This exe generates random strings like "go" "start" etc as a console application


        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        //add event handler when output is received
        p.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => {


        data = e.Data;  //THIS DATA is what i sent though to the other class (one with the carriage return in
        received = true;
        };

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Did you run that test on the string *before* removing the last character?

Comment: That's a carriage return character.  You could either remove it, or Trim() the string

Comment: Ive updated the test Results (had a variable "go" coded in for previous testing)

Comment: I Take it, every time my console application went to a new line, it sent that carriage return with.

Comment: The carriage return returns the cursor to the first character on the line, while the newline character sets it down to the next line.  Windows tends to use a carriage return followed by a newline to start a new line.  I'm not sure what effect a CR by itself would have on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this possible?

You've shown there isn't any whitespace. That doesn't mean there isn't a non-printable character.

The simplest diagnostic is to just print out the "odd" Unicode value:

```
print((int) receivedCom[receivedCom.Length - 1]);
```

I'm guessing it'll be 0, and it's just an off-by-one error in how you're reading the data.

EDIT: Of course to show *exactly* what's in the string, just print everything:

```
print ("Length: " + receivedCom.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < receivedCom.Length; i++)
{
    print("receivedCom[" + i + "] = " + (int) receivedCom[i];
}
```

If you could edit the result of that into the question, we can make progress.

Comment: It could be the first or second character too, probably better to loop over it?

Comment: @Esailija: Not in the example given, where removing the last character did the trick.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I dont think it can be in the front since i removed Something from the back, and still got the word "go"? Or im i wrong again

Comment: @JonSkeet the way I saw it was that even after removing last character "it still didn't want to work with it" :P

Comment: @Ruan: That's odd - 111 is `o`. Can you show the full trace of that case?

Comment: @Esailija: Hmm... there does seem to be something odd going on.

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe it really was the last character, and the string literal in `"go".Equals` also has the extra character when it's tested so it's not equal? :D

Comment: @JonSkeet Scratch that, i used a temp variable called "go" so thats wrong, im updating my results now

Comment: @Ruan: Okay, now we're getting somewhere - 13 is "carriage return". Different console outputs will handle that in different ways, but it sounds like it's effectively being ignored in your case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh okay..No idea how that got in there... So if I would remove that (by means of my one method in my question) is it then necessaries to convert it to a String Again (or something - Reason I ask is because it still didn't work in my if statement)

Comment: @Ruan: Given previous diagnostic failures, I suspect this is another one. I'd be *very* surprised if you could provide a program which would let us reproduce that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ive accepted the fact that all my input will have a "carriage return" with, so running the removal code again (knowing that there is an invisible return there now) it is working - well going into the if. I didn't know that carriage returns can sneak into your strings like that.. So Thank you, You really did help me allot

Comment: @Ruan: Well they don't sneak in magically. Without knowing anything about where they came from, I can't really help you to avoid them.

Comment: @JonSkeet Im Writing an update on how i got the value from in my question now

Comment: @Ruan: I suspect this is an artefact of Unity in this case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon - Will look up Unity and Artefacts

Comment: @Ruan: No, artifact (I typo'd it before) isn't a technical term here. I mean it's just an oddity in the way Unity works compared with (say) the full .NET framework.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh Okay I get, haha thank you. (I always hated working with unity)